# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

My attempt:
$\mathbb{Z}_2 $has elements of the form $\{1,x\}$  and $\mathbb{Z}_2  \times  \mathbb{Z}_2$ has elements of the form $\{(1,1),(1,x),(x, 1),(x, x) \}$ order of $(1,1)=1$, order of $(1,x) ,(x, x)$  and $(x, 1)$ is $2$. Since none of the elements have order =4 . It is not a cyclic group as there is no generator.  Am I correct?

Comment: You are right. In general, $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ will be cyclic if and only if $(m,n)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good to me. There can be no single generator because no element has high enough order, thus the group is not cyclic.

Comment: Is there any other method to show?

Comment: @Guria Sona  Yes: a cyclic group of order $n$ will have precisely one subgroup of order $k$ for each divisor $k$ of $n$; however, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has $3$ subgroups of order $2$ while being a group of order $4$.

Comment: Can we say something about groups which have infinite order?  What about $Z_2\times Z$? Surely any element of the form (1,n)cannot generate (1,x) and vice versa.. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: @GuriaSona Well, your reasoning isn't perfect, but that's basically it. If there are both elements of finite order and elements of infinite order, then the group cannot be cyclic. And if all elements have infinite order, then the only cyclic group is $\Bbb Z$. This will be easier once you come across the theorem called _the classification of finitely generated abelian groups_ (or something along those lines).

Comment: @Arthur All elements of infinite order *except the neutral element*.

Comment: @egreg Very true and a thing I shouldn't have missed.